# Fail to mock a function of react component props

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I am writing UT for a react component with Jest.
I fail to mock a function of react component props.

Here is the dev code

```
// dev code 
class export class NamespaceRow extends Component {
  // omit some code here 
  toggleNs = () => {
    const { fetchTables } = this.props
    const { id } = namespace
    fetchTables(dsId, id)
    this.setState({ expanded: true })
  }
 // omit some code here
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchTables: bindActionCreators(getTables, dispatch),
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NamespaceRow)
```

Here is the UT code.

```
describe('NamespaceRow/index.test.js', () => {
  let store
  let component
  let instance
  let props
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({})
    props = {}
    component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NamespaceRow {...props} />
      </Provider>
    )
// get the component instance
    instance = component.root.children[0].children[0].instance
  })
// test code A
it('when calling toggleNS', () => {
  instance.props = {
    ...instance.props,
    fetchTables: jest.fn(),
  }
// toggleNs is called successfully
  instance.toggleNs()
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined
  expect(instance.props.fetchTables.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
})
})
```

And If I change the UT code a little below. It works!

```
// test code B
it('when calling toggleNS', () => {
  const mockFetchTables = jest.fn()
  instance.props = {
    ...instance.props,
    fetchTables: mockFetchTables,
  }
  instance.toggleNs()
  expect(mockFetchTables.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
}
```

So why the test code A fails while test code test B passes?

#### Update:

After further investigation, I found this question is duplicated with my another question, [setState makes me fail to mock a component prop function from mapDispatchToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075072/setstate-makes-me-fail-to-mock-a-component-prop-function-from-mapdispatchtoprops)

So I will close/delete/mark as duplciated it.

Comment: Is `mockFetchTables` defined in the first example snippet? Doesn't look like it is.

Comment: @DrewReese The first example snippet has been updated.  Thanks for correction.