# setState makes me fail to mock a component prop function from mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I have a component called `NamespaceMenu` below.

```
export class NamespaceMenu extends Component {
// omit some code here 
  refreshNamespace = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    this.setState({
      ...this.initialState,
      isRefreshing: true,
    })
    fetchNamespaces()
  }
// omit some code here 
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchNamespaces: bindActionCreators(getNameSpaces, dispatch),
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NamespaceMenu)
```

I write a UT for this component

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import NamespaceMenu from '../index'

jest.mock('@lib/TextSearchHighlight', () => () => <div>TextSearchHighlight</div>)
jest.mock('lib/Button', () => () => <div>Button</div>)
jest.mock('../SearchBox', () => () => <div>SearchBox</div>)
jest.mock('../../../../LoadingWaitbox', () => () => <div>LoadingWaitBox</div>)
jest.mock('../../../../../InformationWithDetails', () => () => <div>InformationWithDetails</div>)

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const namespaces = [
  {
    id: 'id1',
    name: 'ns1',
    shouldDisplay: true,
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    name: 'ns2',
    shouldDisplay: false,
  },
]

describe('NamespaceMenu/index.js', () => {
  let store
  let component
  let instance
  let props
  let mockCleanHandler
  let mockLoadSelectedDataSources
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockCleanHandler = jest.fn()
    mockLoadSelectedDataSources = jest.fn()
    props = {
      cleanHandler: mockCleanHandler,
      visible: true,
      dbRoleId: 'dbRoleId1',
    }
    store = mockStore({
      dbRoleId: namespaces,
    })
    component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NamespaceMenu {...props} />
      </Provider>
    )
    instance = component.root.children[0].children[0].instance
    instance.props = {
      ...instance.props,
      expandDbRole: jest.fn(),
      setNamespaceDisplayState: jest.fn(),
      loadSelectedDataSources: mockLoadSelectedDataSources,
    }
  })
// UT code A
  it('when calling refreshNamespace', () => {
    const mockFetchNamespaces = jest.fn()
    // without the code below
    // instance.setState = jest.fn()
    instance.props = {
      ...instance.props,
      fetchNamespaces: mockFetchNamespaces,
    }
    instance.refreshNamespace()
expect(mockFetchNamespaces.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

There is an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNameSpaces' of undefined

This error is thrown from the implemention code of `fetchNamespaces`.
Yes, the code fails to mock `fetchNamespaces`

The I change the code a little.
I mock the `setState`. It works!

```
// UT code B
it('when calling refreshNamespace', () => {
    const mockFetchNamespaces = jest.fn()
// The line below is added. Yes, I mock the `setState`
    instance.setState = jest.fn()
    instance.props = {
      ...instance.props,
      fetchNamespaces: mockFetchNamespaces,
    }
    instance.refreshNamespace()
expect(mockFetchNamespaces.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
  })
```

Why UT code A fails and UT code B passes?
It seems that `setState` is the key to the question.

Comment: Is this question significantly different than your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074605/fail-to-mock-a-function-of-react-component-props)?

Comment: Yes, this question is related to `setState` while that question is not.

Comment: @DrewReese After further investigation, I found that question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64074605/fail-to-mock-a-function-of-react-component-props,  is also related to `setState`. So that question is duplicated.

Comment: You truncated the important part of the test. How do you import the component? If you're testing connected component, props obviously won't be mocked.

Comment: @EstusFlask Added. I import the connected component.